# Nested Library Projects. Accesing to jars

Tags: android, android-library

I have 2 library project and one main project.
Current structure:
Main Project -> (depends on) 1 Library project -> 2 Library project.

2 Library project contains .jar, that I want to access from Main Project. But I get NoClassDefFound exception, when I am running application on device.

Note:
1. 2 Library project exportes .jar and private libraries
2. 1 Library project exportes 2 library projects and private libraries.
3. I am using build tools v17.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to launch activities and use classes in your main project that are in 2 Library Project? If so that is probably what is causing your issue.

You are thinking about your library projects in the wrong way. If you have a Main project like yours it needs to include every project that it depends on. For example say you have a main project that needs two libraries B and C, but both libraries also rely on library A.

It does NOT look like this

MAIN 

   -> LIB A

LIB B

   -> LIB A

LIB C

   -> LIB A

Rather it should look like this:

MAIN

   -> LIB A

   -> LIB B

   -> LIB C

LIB B

   -> LIB A

LIB C

   -> LIB A

Thus you should be able to solve your problems by including the 2 Library Project in your Main Project as well as the 1 Library project.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I am interesting, why it must be done in such way. Do you have a link to android developers site, where this information is mentioned?

Comment: I don't know of any specific documentation. I use a very complex project setup and eventually learned that I could separate my code better by using the solution above.

You may actually be able to do it how you were originally but you will probably have to specify the exact class location when you start activities for example: startActivity(new Intent(this, com.liba.xxx.ClassName))

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok have you solved it with the above solution?

Comment: No, it was just an issue with Eclipse build system.